# How to mutate a new col in dataframe using a specific function and conditions? Tidyverse/R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

First of all, I couldn't find a question related with my issue, apologies if this question was already answered.

I have a dataframe with some columns and I want to calculate a new value using a specific ecuation. I guess I have to use `mutate()` from tidyverse, but I want to avoid rows/samples where there're one or more 0 values. I don't know how I can check  if there's any 0 when I'm using `mutate()`. Also, I don't know how I can apply my specific formula to create the new column.

I leave here a code to create a dataframe as an example of my issue.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  time = seq(now(), now()+hours(11),by='hours'),
  a = sample(0:100,12),
  b = sample(0:100,12),
  c = sample((0:20)/1000,12))

df[1:3,]$a <- 0
df[3:5,]$b <- 0
df[3:4,]$c <- 0

# function: M = a*b+(1-e^(-c/2))
# if any 0 in the row -> M = NA
# else: apply function
```

The function could be written as

```
a*b*(1-exp(-c/2))
```

The final df should have 4 colums per each hour (row) (a,b,c and the new calculated M), but when `a | b | c == 0, M = NA`.

I will be very grateful for every little help. Cheers!

EDIT: The real function is more complex that this example, so it will not be always true that if one term (a,b,c,...) is 0, the resulting M is 0. Sorry, I didn't realised this postulate is true for the simplified equation.
But I want to avoid any 0 value because they are from monitoring physiological variables and I know if one value is 0 in a sample, then the sample is wrong, so NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of `a`, `b` or `c` is 0 it returns `M` as 0 which can be changed to `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(M = a*b*(1-exp(-c/2)), 
         M = na_if(M, 0))

#                  time  a  b     c         M
#1  2021-10-18 19:41:56  0 90 0.013        NA
#2  2021-10-18 20:41:56  0 56 0.016        NA
#3  2021-10-18 21:41:56  0  0 0.000        NA
#4  2021-10-18 22:41:56 13  0 0.000        NA
#5  2021-10-18 23:41:56 66  0 0.011        NA
#6  2021-10-19 00:41:56 41 71 0.014 20.305847
#7  2021-10-19 01:41:56 49 25 0.009  5.500115
#8  2021-10-19 02:41:56 42  6 0.012  1.507473
#9  2021-10-19 03:41:56 97 41 0.017 33.661237
#10 2021-10-19 04:41:56 24 97 0.008  9.293401
#11 2021-10-19 05:41:56 89 82 0.019 69.002718
#12 2021-10-19 06:41:56 68 35 0.015 17.783230
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, maybe it was not the best example, I tried to simplify the dataset and the equation. The equation is simplified. For example,in the original one  is an added term, so it wont be true that if one term is 0, M would be 0. I will post the original equation here:

 a*b*(c+d(1-exp(-e/(f*g))))

I'm using letters to make it easier to understand. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Do you know if it s a way to use the condition as I asked originally, without using this 'mathematical' trick you posted?

Comment: If there is a way to use something like 'M = na_if(M, 0)' part, but, instead of M, looking for 0 in a,b,c,... , it will be enough, but i don't know any function like that. Ty

Comment: At the end, I used your approach but the other way round. First, I replaced all 0 with NA values, so the equation will return NA. I will tick your reply as the solution. I would still appreciate to know if there is a way to do it with conditions, though.

Comment: @RobertoT How about `df %>% mutate(M = ifelse(if_any(a:c, ~. == 0), NA, a*b*(1-exp(-c/2))))` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know if_any. That's a great solution.